# Determine exact type/class of object

Tags: javascript, servicenow

If I've a variable and I want to know what exactly is the type of object, how would I do that?

```
// this prints "object"
// any way to know what kind of object
// like whether a GlideRecord or Reference Field or array or json?
gs.log(typeof myVariable);
```

Comment: What you're asking is, strictly-speaking, impossible (because JavaScript is structurally-typed, not *nominatively-typed*). Objects in JavaScript don't need a specific prototype or constructor to conform to a TypeScript interface or `type` definition, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If `GlideRecord` and so on are classes or constructor functions, you can use the `constructor` property.

```js
class GlideRecord {}
// or legacy constructor function - 
// function GlideRecord() {}

const instance = new GlideRecord()

const { constructor } = instance

console.log(constructor)                 // GlideRecord
console.log(constructor.name)            // "GlideRecord"
console.log(constructor === GlideRecord) // true
```

Note that this will *not* work if they're just plain old JS objects created with *factory* functions - in this case, `constructor` will simply be `Object`:

```js
const createGlideRecord = () => {
    return { /* ... */ }
}

const instance = createGlideRecord()

const { constructor } = instance

console.log(constructor)                       // Object
console.log(constructor.name)                  // "Object"
console.log(constructor === createGlideRecord) // false
```